# Best approach to display large number of images from disk

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, image, dictionary

This question is gonna be purely theoretical, so bear with me for a second.

I have a folder with tens of thousands of *.jpg images.
Then I have a list of objects. Each object has a `timestamp`. The `timestamp` is the name of a file.

The endgame is to display the object data with the related image. One each 20ms.

My first approach was to create a `Dictionary<double, byte[]>` (where `double` indicates the timestamp, and `byte[]` is the converted image) preloading all the images and loading them in the ImageView when needed.

The other approach would be to use a `Dictionary<double, Path>` (where `Path` is the path to the image) to point at the image and load it from the disk at run time.

Consider that I may need to preload something like 300k images ~50KB each, which may be overkill for the system, So I may be forced to "lazy-load" a smaller amount each time (let say 5k)

On the other hand, I will have to load every 20ms of an image from the disk. Which I don't know if it is expensive in terms of performances.

What would you suggest as the better option?
Do you have any other solution at hand?

Comment: If you want to show a movie, why don't you render your images to be a movie?

Comment: The entire data collection is also shown on a table. Selecting a row will display the related image. And the images can be scrolled forward or backward by single steps. The "20ms" thingy is a play option.

Answer (score 0):

Are you making some sort of movie player with pause and frame-by-frame browsing functionality? Assuming you do, I've came up with the following:

Doing a quick math: 300.000 images 50 kB each is 15 GB. Can your system handle keeping this in memory (`Dictionary<double, byte[]>`)?
300.000 images, each one played for 20 ms is a movie of almost 2 hours (100 minutes) at 50 fps. Do you need to have the whole movie in memory at all times?

I'd suggest:

- keep the filenames, as you planned, i.e.: `Dictionary<double, Path>` as the access reference to all your frames
- prepare some kind of ring buffer for, say, 10 seconds of movie (check empirically, how long it takes to load another 10 seconds of frames into memory), just experiment with the optimal buffer size
- for the preview - I can't imagine a 300.000 rows table with images for easy preview. I'd rather put a horizontal preview bar with the images poping-up, like in the YouTube player.

In the preview window you can use the hardware limitation in your favour - say your preview window is 1000 pixels wide. This means that the operator can quickly spot only 1000 images spread over those 100 minutes of the movie (1 image for every 6 seconds) because the mouse and display resolution are the limiting factors. Store those 1000 images in memory and fill the buffer upon the operator click.

Let me know if my assumptions concerning your assignment are correct.

Comment: I'm not trying to make a movie. The resolutino of the images is less than 400x400. And they come from a camera places on a machine that takes 1img every 20ms.
Luckily I'm not working connected in real time, but I have to use hours of that camera recordings.
But your assumptions on the memory usage are correct. And I don't have 15Gigs of memory to spend there.
I'll got with the path option and check how fast is the system to read from the disk.

Answer (score 0):

I had custom a ListView to display Images using lazy-load, hope it help:
XAML:

```
<ListView
    x:Name="imageList"
    Margin="2"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
    Background="Transparent"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ImageList}"
    Loaded="imageList_Loaded"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border
                Width="100"
                Height="100"
                MaxHeight="100"
                Margin="0"
                BorderBrush="#0080DD"
                BorderThickness="1"
                MouseDown="ImageItem_MouseDown">
                <Grid>
                    <Image
                        Loaded="Image_Loaded"
                        Stretch="Uniform"
                        Tag="{Binding Path}" />
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

.cs:

```
private void imageList_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ScrollViewer scrollViewer = imageList.GetVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(); //Extension method
    if (scrollViewer != null)
    {
        ScrollBar scrollBar = scrollViewer.Template.FindName("PART_VerticalScrollBar", scrollViewer) as ScrollBar;
        if (scrollBar != null)
        {
            scrollBar.ValueChanged += delegate
            {
                UpdateImages();
            };
        }
    }
}

public void UpdateImages()
{
    //VerticalOffset and ViweportHeight is actually what you want if UI virtualization is turned on.
    var visibleItems = (imageList as Visual).GetVisualChilds<System.Windows.Controls.Image>();
    foreach (var image in visibleItems)
    {
        UpdateImageSource(image);
    }
}

private static bool IsUserVisible(FrameworkElement element, FrameworkElement container)
{
    if (!element.IsVisible)
        return false;

    Rect bounds =
        element.TransformToAncestor(container).TransformBounds(new Rect(0.0, 0.0, element.ActualWidth, element.ActualHeight));
    var rect = new Rect(0.0, 0.0, container.ActualWidth, container.ActualHeight);
    return rect.Contains(bounds.TopLeft) || rect.Contains(bounds.BottomRight);
}

private void UpdateImageSource(System.Windows.Controls.Image image)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        image.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            var path = image.Tag as string;
            if (IsUserVisible(image, imageList))
            {
                if (image.Source == null)
                    image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(path));
            }
            else if (image.Source != null)
                image.Source = null;
        });
    });
}

private void Image_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateImageSource(sender as System.Windows.Controls.Image);
}
```